# ListBox does not show object's ToString() when it is binded

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, binding, listbox

I have a ListBox which is binded to instance of Class A, which is a collection.

```
class A : List<B> 
{ 
  public override ToString()
  {
    return "A";
  }
}
```

ListBox:

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding instanceOfA}"></ListBox>
```

When the application is run, every item shows "(Collection)"

What can I do to make each item show "A" instead of "Collection"?

Comment: Are you binding a single `A` or a list of `A`s?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order do what you are trying to do, you should have something like this

```
class B
{
  public override ToString()
  {
    return "A";
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The ListBox calls `ToString` on each item of the collection, that means your method never gets called. You'd need to override the `ToString()` in `B`.